# Why is my spring application not building properly?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, build, compilation

I was working on a spring application, I don't know what happened with config but it's not building correctly anymore.

```
[ERROR] Invalid packaging for parent POM com.good.gut:GoodGut:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, must be "pom" but is "jar" @ 
[ERROR] Invalid packaging for parent POM com.good.gut:GoodGut:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, must be "pom" but is "jar" @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.2.5.RELEASE
```

[image showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFYbS.png)

[mvn clean from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ak7Xu.png)

Comment: You pom as already stated by the error message is not defined `<packaging>pom</packaging>` cause it defines module I suppose..

Comment: Yes, i tried that which I found in other questions but didn't work for me. Finally removing the repository folder and reinstalling dependencies solved it. Ty